# files (Nautilus) appearing twice in alt+tab switcher

Tags: unity, application-switcher

I've been getting an odd bug where a single window of files shows up twice in the alt-tab switcher.  See screenshots: in expose there is only one instance of files, but in alt-tab there is two.  I do have other windows open in other workspaces, but both alt-tab instances refer to the same window (since that is where they take me).

Has anyone else seen this/know what's causing it/how to stop it from happening?

[image: note the double instance of files, both of which take me to the same window]

[image: but in expose only a single instance]